# libgstapp-1.0.so.0 is not an ELF file

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, libraries

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10. This was a clean install, not an upgrade. I'm not sure what I did, but when I use `apt` to install packages, at the end, the following error are printed:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) ... /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 is not an ELF file
- it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0.803.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0.803.0 is not an ELF file
- it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
```

I suspect that this is causing problems in some of the applications that I am using, but I don't know ho to fix it short of reinstalling everything. What can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-installing the package which provides these files should fix things:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
```